# NSInvalidArgumentException Reason - [xxxx backdropView:willChangeToGraphicsQuality]

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am using Xamarin and after updating to iOS 7 sdk my application keeps crashing...I have a function that I pass into my second view controller from my first view controller as an action that simply is:

```
    public void Dismiss()
    {
     try{
        this.PresentedViewController.DismissViewController (false, null);
        }    
    catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(path, "log.txt");
                File.AppendAllText(filePath,"\n" + DateTime.Now + "\tISSUE:\t Closing colletions detail tab...\n\n" + ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
    }
```

Now the application is crashes even after catching the exception. What gets printed in my log is:

```
Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: [UILabel backdropView:willChangeToGraphicsQuality:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18c8ee40 at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSendSuper_bool_IntPtr (intptr,intptr, bool, intptr) at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.DismissViewController(Boolean animated, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction completionHandler) [0x00057] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs 747 at YltraRoute.MainViewController.CloseCollectionDetailTab()[0x00011]...
```

I don't even know where to start with this. There is not much help out there.

Oh and its not always [UILabel backdropView... its sometime UIScrollViewPanGuestureRecognizer

So I have done more searching and it seems that this may be a memory issue (object already garbage collected).

I got that info from [here](http://imlocation.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/strange-objects-nscftype-indicate-memory-management-bugs/) as another version of the fault was:

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[__NSCFType backdropView:willChangeToGraphicsQuality:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1eb3ad70
```

So if this is truly the case how do I go about this. There is no way that the presenting view controller could be released already right? And the presented view controller is declared globally in my class as well.

Comment: I am seeing this in my native app. If I find a solution I'll let you know.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution eventually? I'm getting crashes for this as well

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the `.DismissViewController` method. I'll try to explain why.

When navigating to a new ViewController, you use the `PushViewController` method. The view you're creating inside the parameters gets added to a stack. So, for example:

- You have ViewController A, B and C
- Your main ViewController is set to A inside your AppDelegate

So, when you open up your app, the stack looks like this:

```
|     |
|     |
|     |
|  A  |
```

When adding B and C with the `PushViewController`, it looks like this:

```
|     |
|  C  |
|  B  |
|  A  |
```

Now, I hear you asking: but why don't I have to use the `DismissViewController` method? Well, there's another method called `PopToViewController`. This is used to navigate to another ViewController that's already on the stack. In the example, you're currently inside ViewController C (as it is on the top of the stack). If you wanted to navigate to ViewController B, you can search the stack to determine wether it is in there, and navigate to it. Here's a little block of code for it:

```
ViewController_B view_B = null;

foreach (var item in this.NavigationController.ViewControllers) 
{
    if (item is ViewController_B) 
    {
        view_B = (ViewController_B)item;
    }
}

if (view_B != null) 
{
    this.NavigationController.PopToViewController (view_B, true);
}
```

Now, what happens is, you'll pop to ViewController B, but since it's not the top of the stack, it throws away (garbage collects) ViewController C. This way, you don't need to manually dismiss C.

Same goes for if you wanted to navigate from ViewController C to ViewController A. Same method, but now, it throws away ViewController C AND ViewController B.

But what if the ViewController I want to navigate to doesn't already exist? You can add an `else` statement underneath the example code I just pasted, like this:

```
if (view_B != null) 
{
    this.NavigationController.PopToViewController (view_B, true);
}

else
{
    this.NavigationController.PushViewController (new ViewController_D, true);
}
```

Note that this method only works when using ViewControllers, in which you house your UI (`public class ViewController_B : UIViewController`).

To add the answer to the question of how to invoke a method from one `ViewController to another` (when navigating to it), there's a few options. I'll list the method I use.

When navigating to another `ViewController`, wether this is with `PopToViewController` or `PushViewController`, the `Virtual` method (from the abstract class `UIViewController`) `ViewWillAppear` will always be called. If you want an action to be executed once per navigation to a `ViewController`, you can place it inside this overridden method.

I hope this information helps you. Good luck!

Love and regards,
Björn